# Frontend redirection to SSO form via microservice + keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, keycloak, single-sign-on

In my project, the frontend for authentication does not go to Keycloak directly: first it makes a request to the Spring Boot microservice, which in turn must request the desired Keycloak realm. Keycloak will then return the token to the microservice, and the microservice will return the token to the frontend.

This scenario works well for native authentication, but there are problems with authentication via SSO.

When requesting, the frontend needs to be immediately redirected to the SSO provider’s login form (bypassing the Keycloak form). After the data is entered into the SSO form, a redirect should occur back to the frontend with the received token.

Is it possible to do this with a single request from the frontend and not go directly to Keycloak?

Comment: I believe you're looking for idP initiated login.  Your backend redirects the web client to the sso provider which is then configured to go back to keycloak with a token once the user has entered credentials.